# Geolocation with HTML 5 & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I am currenlty wokring on my first mobile web app and have already loaded google maps into my application using Geolocation JavaScript API version3.Now I want a button which each time user clicks it the map shows my location centered on the page.Having said that my application is mainly written in HTML5.Any solution for that?
Thanking you

Comment: I have no idea how to write a code for handling an event (such as clicking a button) in HTML5.

Comment: Then what did you search for?

Comment: It sounds your question has more to do with event-handling (specifically capturing click events) and manipulating Google Maps than with geolocation or HTML5. You should probably change the question title to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo with input controls & a button, you should be able to figure it out from there:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html

Comment: Thanks...I used the page...it was pretty useful :)